Spring Boot + Angular monolith application csrf-token is being set as HttpOnly in external server where https is used
Locally I get as a response header correctly after GET request
SET-COOKIE: XSRF-TOKEN=cookie; Path=/

And when doing POST request it has cookie and a header and everything is working fine.
In external server where the application is being server over HTTPS the XSRF-TOKEN is being set as
SET-COOKIE: XSRF-TOKEN=cookie; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly

So that makes the request fail because angular frontend cannot access the cookie to put it into a header.
This is my SecurityConfiguration.java file
.csrf(csrf ->
            csrf
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                .csrfTokenRequestHandler(new SpaCsrfTokenRequestHandler())
                .ignoringRequestMatchers(mvc.pattern("/api/logout"))
        )
.... some other stuff here
.addFilterAfter(new CookieCsrfFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)

In external server I am using default tomcat setup basically.
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">

<!-- HTTP to HTTPS redirection -->
<Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />


<Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true">
    <SSLHostConfig>
        <Certificate certificateFile="crt"
                     certificateKeyFile="key"
                     certificateChainFile="crt"
                     type="RSA" />
    </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>

        <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="myurl.com">
            <Host name="myurl.com" appBase="webapps"
                  unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
            </Host>
        </Engine>
    </Service>

</Server>

Can it be that tomcat somehow overwrites these cookies or what are my options here?

This explained in the CSRF chapter of the spring security docs in the subsection conveniently named ”Javascript applications” https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/exploits/csrf.html#csrf-integration-javascript

Could you elaborate more please, which place exactly? I am doing these things it suggests and in http it works correctly.

Your code looks nothing like the link i posted, start there and if you have question point out specifically what parts of the docs you dont understand and i will elaborate on those parts. Im not going to teach you something that is already documented.

I implemented the example in the Single-Page-Application block. Locally with http the cookie is httpOnly false. In external server with https it is still HttpOnly true so it does not work and cookie is not being put into the header as Angular cannot read it.

So you are claiming that the spring documentation is wrong then? if you are actually serious of asking for help, you need to supply a small reproducible example, as it is clear that somewhere in your code there is a problem but you have litteraly just shown us 3 lines of code. I cant run your code, you have supplied no logs, no stack traces i cant run it. Im leaving now, good luck

No, I am trying to find out whats causing it. Couls it be somethjng overwriting it to be in my external server with httponly true. As I stated everything works locally. I will try turning https of on external server to see if it starts working.

your tomcat configuraiton is completely irrelevant to the HttpOnly flag being seit. My guess is that the issue is inside of CookieCsrfFilter - please show its code

public class CookieCsrfFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
    CsrfToken csrfToken = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
    response.setHeader(csrfToken.getHeaderName(), csrfToken.getToken());
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}

}

it's likely that .class.getName() call is a hack to get around an architecture problem.  I would suspect that code could be creating a cookie for use with double-cookie pattern or something.  I'd try using the documented method.  It should handle writing the cookie you need to read with Angular's HttpClientXsrfModule.  The ".addFilterAfter(new CookieCsrfFilter()" looks odd too.

you should also know that HttpClientXsrfModule will not send the header unless you use absolute paths.... may need secure (https) as well there.  (it doesn't seem to be well documented)

I started server with https locally, then it worked. So it's something with my server, that maybe overwrites the cookie.
